# How to display contents of routes on the website in selected fields in Ember

Tags: html, css, ember.js

I'm doing a small project in Ember, which I'm really new to. I have an Ember app with a main page/route.

[Main pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CftEm.png)

What I want is that if I click on "About" etc., the contents of that route (some text, pic, whatever) will be displayed on the page in left column let's say, or wherever else I want it on the page.

So far everything I tried makes the contents appear under the footer.
I tried doing this in about.hbs, thinking that if I specify the position of the contents with , which is how the page is sectioned in the index.html file, it would work. But no, all it does is creating an identical left column under the footer.

```
    {{page-title "About"}}
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "left-col">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ember uses a tree for routing. The `application` route is the root of the tree. All other routes are child of the `application` route.

Routes are registered in `app/router.js`. The `application` route is not registered explicitly.

If a route has at least one child an `index` route is created automatically.

Let's the example from the [official Ember tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/building-pages/) to illustrate:

```js
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from 'super-rentals/config/environment';

export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('about');
});
```

It registers a `about` route as you are trying to do. This creates the following routing tree:

- application

  - index
  - about

A child route is rendered within the `{{outlet}}` of its parent route.

Let's take an example again. Let's assume you created this three template:

```
{{!
  app/templates/application.hbs
  template for application route
}}

<div class="container">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

```
{{!
  app/templates/index.hbs
  template for index route
}}

<p>Landing page</p>
```

```
{{!
  app/templates/about.hbs
  template for about route
}}

<p>About me</p>
```

If a user visits the index route the following HTML markup will be rendered:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Landing page</p>
</div>
```

If a user visits the about route the following HTML will be rendered:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Please find more information about this in [routing chapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/) of Ember's official guides.